# A question about date

Tags: grammaticality, dates

A standard date question would be:

> What date is it today?

But is

> What date is today?

acceptable?

Comment: "What **day** is today?" would be probably correct; not "What date is today?"

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  On second thought, should we consider spoken and written English separately for an answer?

Comment: My comment is not related to spoken/written differences. It mentions **day** vs. **date**.

Answer (score 0):

"What's *the* date today?" would be better!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Just wish to know whether the construct "What date is today ?" is used at all by native speakers.

Comment: Sorry English is not native language. But yeah in the following link the person who has answered a similar question has the native language as English :

http://www.englishforums.com/English/WhatsTheDateDayToday/dbgkm/post.htm

hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just find out that this question has been asked before.  A more complete answer can be found below.

["What day is it today?" vs. "What day is today?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81357/what-day-is-it-today-vs-what-day-is-today)

But as Matt has suggested.  This question should be posted on an ELL site.