# What is today's date vs What date is it today?

Tags: phrases, questions

What is today's date vs What date is it today ?

Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: They mean exactly the same thing and both are correct; similarly *What's the date today?*

Comment: [“What day is it today?” vs. “What day is today?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81357/what-day-is-it-today-vs-what-day-is-today) I can't vote to close this question as a dupe. Someone else do it for me.

Comment: Related: [Can we interchange phrases “ What's the date today?” and “what day is it today?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156269/can-we-interchange-phrases-whats-the-date-today-and-what-day-is-it-today)

Answer (score 0):

Both denote the same thing in the sense that the ultimate thing asked for is the clarification for what is that day's date.